# How to find the nth element that has a class of .foo in the document with Capybara/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to find the n-th element that has a special class in a document. The elements are not necessarily children of the same parent. So for example

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="foo">This</div></li>
  <li><div>Nothing</div>
    <ul>
      <li><div class="foo">This also</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div class="foo">And this</div><li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to find the first, second or third element that has the class `.foo`.

I tried

```ruby
page.find '.foo'
```

Which errors in `Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 3 elements matching css ".foo"`

I then tried

```ruby
page.all('.foo')[n]
```

Which works nice except that it doesn't seem to wait this little time like Capybaras `find` does, which I need because the HTML is actually generated from ajax data. So how to do this correctly with find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a short chat in #RubyOnRails on freenode it became clear to me that this isn't as easy possible as it sounds first. The problem is that Capybara can't know if the `.foo`s that are already inserted into the page are "all" of them. Thats why `.all` has no (or doesn't need) support for waiting like `.find` has.

The solution would be to manually wait for an appropriate amount of time and then just use `.all`.

Answer (score -1):

Nokogiri's CSS queries are effective for finding elements of certain classes. It is explained in [the tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).

For example you can use the following Ruby one-liner to read from a given file and find the second element of class `foo`:

```ruby
ruby -rnokogiri -e 'puts Nokogiri::HTML(readlines.join).css(".foo")[1]' sample.html
```

which returns

```html
<div class="foo">This also</div>
```

Replace the number in `[1]` with the index of the element you want to find and replace `sample.html` with the html file you want to search in. If you want to pick out certain parts of the elements you can use methods of `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, e.g. [`content`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-content) to get its contents.

Comment: This answer totally misses the point that there is no html document that can be parsed but html content that is loaded into existing html via ajax.

Comment: @ohcibi Reading from a file was just an example to show off Nokigiri. Could you provide some example in your question of how the html is loaded?

Comment: The point is: `.find` does wait a configurable amount of time before it returns false when you try to `find` an element (as it could be inserted asynchronously). `.all` doesn't; it returns false immediatly if the document doesn't contains the searched element. I pointed out why it is like this in my answer. Looks like the nokogiri tag on my question was way to confusing 8-)

Comment: @ohcibi Well, if you can get Nokogiri's search method to have appropriately when it comes to timing it seems that they can also do the job.

Comment: I dont understand what you are talking about. But Nokogiri has nothing to do with this problem (I removed the tag). Read the answer I posted. I think the case is closed at this point except someone has a better solution than I posted in my answer.

Comment: @ohcibi Sorry, I was unclear. I meant to write "if you can get Nokogiri's search methods to behave appropriately when it comes to timing it seems that they can also do the job", i.e. if the solution for Capybara has to do with getting the right timing of when to search then it seems that Nokogiri could solve it too given that it gets the timing right.

Comment: thats what my answer is proposing 8-))